# C Left Shift Operator

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    
    int x = 8;
    printf("%d %d %d ", x++, x << 2, x >> 1);
 
}
```

The way I feel like this is supposed to go is this way:
The first number should be 8. Then it gets incremented to 9. 9<<2 is 36 so the second %d is 36. The last one is 8 >> 1 which is 4.

However, when I put this into the compiler I get '8 32 4' and not '8 36 4'.

Can someone explain why please?

Thank you!

Comment: Function arguments can be evaluated in any order. So the order of side effects is also not guaranteed.

Comment: @P__J__ you are right, it's the wrong dupe. Better would be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points although that's labelled C++ rather than C (although in this case, it's the same).

Answer (score 2):

This operation invokes an Undefined Behavior.

The gcc executes the way you observe, `clang` does it another way as the result of this program is undefined.

`clang` also issues a warning

https://godbolt.org/z/GzhPKn

The make program result defined:

```
int main ()
{    
    int x = 8;
    x++;
    printf("%d %d %d ", x, x << 2, x >> 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Argument evaluation order in C and C++ is undefined. Whether the increment or one of the shifts happens first depends on implementation and compiler optimization. It is never advisable to write code like this.

```
int a() { printf("A"); return 0; }
int b() { printf("B"); return 0; }
int c() { printf("C"); return 0; }
```

If you do:

```
printf("%d%d%d", a(), b(), c());
```

It doesn't necessarily mean you'll get an `ABC` on your console. Ignore the 0s.